# How can I extract the amount written after the 'span' tag under the 'div' tag using css-selectors in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I want to get the amount(182.78) written after `span` tag under `div` tag , but I am getting only the "MRP" element content as a string, I only want to extract the amount written. By the way I'm using ipython as my shell

HTML code:

```
<div class="style__font-bold___1k9Dl style__font-14px___YZZrf style__flex-row___2AKyf style__space-between___2mbvn style__padding-bottom-5px___2NrDR">

<div>Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet</div>

<div>
<span class="style__font-normal___2gZqF style__margin-left-8px___3Sw1d">MRP</span>

₹<!-- -->
182.78

</div>
</div>
```

code i've used

```
med.css('div span ::text').get()
```

and the output of my code is.....-->  **'MRP'**

Comment: Please don't post codes as images. Edit your question and include them as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current selector `'div span ::text'` means that you want the text contents from the span element which is a child of a div element.  However the text that you are trying to extract isn't in contents of the `span` element.

```
<div ...>
   <span ...>MRP</span>
   ...
   <!-- -->
   "132.73"
</div>
```

In order to extract this using a CSS selector, you can use the `:has()` directive to specify the `div` with a `span` as a direct descendant like this:

```
response.css('div:has(> span)::text')
```

And since it is broken by a comment and span tag will want to use the `getall()` method and indicate that you want the last index.

For example:

```
>>> response.css('div:has(> span)::text').getall()[-1]
"132.73"
```